# Android calendar app that allows events with no end time

Tags: android, calendar

I'm looking for an Android calendar app with a very specific feature: I want to be able to add events with no known end time. Don't get me wrong, I'm not talking about "all-day" events which have no start time either; I'm specifically looking to add events that have a start time, but don't have end time.

The very idea of all events having known end times is very confusing to me. If I'm going to a meeting, how do I know if it will last 30 min, 45, or one hour? If I'm going to the movies, how do I know how long will I stay having drinks afterwards? It's very surprising to me that so many apps force people to add some end times which are probably nonsense in 90% of the cases.

Comment: What if the app sets a default end time (e.g., always 1 hour after start time)? Would it be acceptable or not?

Comment: It would not be acceptable unfortunately; the problem is not that I'm annoyed about the fact that I have to enter some ending time. The problem is in the fact that whatever I enter, or is entered by default, is very possibly false. I have a conceptual problem with all events having some known end time and I'm looking for a calendar app that shares my views on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [ToDo Task Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mikesandroidworkshop.android.taskmanager&hl=en_US) can do this. It can show calendar as default view, so I guess that counts as calendar app. There are fields to set due date, start date and end date separately. App has lite and pro versions, I'm not sure if you need paid one for this.

[image]